# monotouch rotate in landscapemode and portrait mode

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, xamarin.ios, orientation

i am new to `iPad` developer,

i have created two or three `iPad` application in objective c using `Xcode 4.`

but now i want to create `iPad` application using `Monodeveloper` tool in `C#` language...

in which, i want to shift my tableView in `orientation`,

i searched in google but i didn't got any syntax.

for detail see my screen shot...

in first image (portrait mode) my Table is at extremeLeft , in second image (landscape mode) i want my table to be at extreme right..

[image: screenshot]
*how should i do this ?*

i created tableview programatically, here is the code snippet,

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            Gainer();   //method call
                UITableView Table=new UITableView();
            Table.Frame=new RectangleF(20,200,400,400);
            Table.Source=new TableViewDataSource(TopGainer); //passing parameter to tableview datasource 
            this.View.AddSubview(Table);


        }

public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            // Return true for supported orientations
            return true;
        }
```

***Any help will be appreciated.***

**Thanks In Advance !!**

Comment: I think you should make your way through the Montouch tutorials (http://ios.xamarin.com/Tutorials) and if you know how to solve things in ObjC, you should easily be able to translate them into C#/Monotouch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `WillRotate` method and apply the exact position you want, in every case, based on the values that `UIScreen.MainScreen` provides. E.g.

```
    public override void WillRotate (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation, double duration)
    {
        switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
            Table.Frame = new RectangleF (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 20 - Table.Frame.Width, 200, 400, 400);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
            Table.Frame = new RectangleF (20, 200, 400, 400);
            break;
        }
        base.WillRotate (toInterfaceOrientation, duration);
    }
```

Comment: dude, i want to call this method in my ViewDidLoad() method how should i call this ?

Comment: You can copy the same code (`switch`) inside your `ViewDidLoad` and call the `base.ViewDidLoad...` however this won't be called when you rotate the device (so your alignment adjustment won't work unless the device is rotated *before* being loaded).

Comment: Don't copy code over, just call the method passing the parameters yourself: WillRotate(InterfaceOrientation, 0);